# conditional expectation substitution in Fisher information

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation, fisher-information

The Fisher information is given by

$$J(\theta) = -E\left[\frac{d^{2}\log p(x | \theta)}{d\theta^{2}} \bigg|~\theta\right]$$

To consider the Fisher information for a binomial parameter:

Let $p(x | \theta) =\binom{n}{x} \theta ^{x} (1 - \theta)^{n - x}$ where $\binom{n}{x}$ is the binomial coefficient.

The log likelihood for the binomial distribution $p(x | \theta)$ is $C_{1} + x \log \theta + (n - y) \log (1 - \theta)$ where $C_{1}$ is a real constant.

The second derivative of the binomial distribution under the log likelihood operation is

$$\frac{d^{2}\log p(x | \theta)}{d\theta^{2}} = \frac{-x}{\theta^{2}} - \frac{(n-x)}{(1 - \theta)^{2}}.$$

How do I proceed to Fisher information evaluating to $\frac{n}{\theta (1 - \theta)}$?

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of $x$ is $n\theta$, so
$$E\left[-\frac{x}{\theta^2}-\frac{n-x}{(1-\theta)^2}\right]=-\frac{n\theta}{\theta^2}-\frac{n-n\theta}{(1-\theta)^2}$$
and from there it is straightforward algebra.